# Entity Framework: saving related entities

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I've got two entities that have a 1-many relation but also a 1-1 relation.

Here's a simple illustration:

```
class Parent
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    public Int32 LastChildId { get; set; }
    public Child LastChild { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

And an instantiation:

```
var c1 = new Child() { };
var c2 = new Child() { };

var p = new Parent()
{
    Children = new List<Child> { c1, c2 },
    LastChild = c2
};
```

Will Entity Framework keep the last child id after the Parent object `p` will be inserted into the db via the datacontext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did:

```
context.Parents.Add(p);
context.SaveChanges();
```

In your above code, that parent `p` will have the ID of `c2` as the value of `LastChildID`.  The parent will also have relationships to both children through the cross-reference table.  Both of those children will have a reference to `p` through it's `Parent` entity property.